# Error when Updating : can't define array index property past the end of an array with non-writable length

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I can add or delete when I haven't saved the data to database. Once it's saved and I want to update them either by deleting them or adding a new value. It gives this error "can't define array index property past the end of an array with non-writable length". How can I solve this issue?

```js
const handleDeleteDepartment = (companyIndex, departmentIndex) => {
  if (departmentIndex !== 0) {
    const newCompanies = [...companies];
    newCompanies[companyIndex].children.splice(departmentIndex, 1);
    setCompanies(newCompanies);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are simply just trying to remove an element from an array at a specific index then I'd suggest (A) using a functional state update to ensure you are updating from the correct previous state value and (B) use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to create a new array reference. Using [`Array.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) mutates an array in-place, and state mutations are a huge no-no in React.

The following applies the immutable update pattern, e.g. all state, and nested state, that is being updated is shallow copied prior to being updated. This ensures all updated state are new references in memory and React can correctly reconcile what needs to be rerendered for the next render cycle.

Example:

```js
const handleDeleteDepartment = (companyIndex, departmentIndex) => {
  if (companyIndex >= 0 && departmentIndex >= 0) {
    setCompanies(companies => companies.map((company, compIndex) => 
      compIndex === companyIndex
        ? {
          ...company,
          children: company.children.filter(
            (_, deptIndex) => deptIndex !== departmentIndex
          ),
        }
        : company
    ));
  }
};
```

Comment: This is a great solution, I agree using state prev value is always better but I don't think here it matters also I want to ask if `slice` is more performant than `.map`, `.filter` when data is large or it does not make a huge difference?  because I have a big data and I want always to use `.filter`

Comment: @AhmedSbai I am inclined to disagree. Just about any time the *next* state value depends on the *previous* state value, you should use a functional state update. This avoids all bugs and issues related to stale closures. With regards to the performance of the array functions, they are all *technically* O(n) operations, i.e. they iterate the array, so the performance should all be relatively similar. Which array method you use though depends on what you need to accomplish.

Comment: thank you very much for explainning.